# How to extract name from tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have this in my graph:

```
output_layer = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(input, output_size, activation_fn=None)
```

I would like to refer to it within another function. Usually, we can name an operation or tensor and use `get_tensor_by_name(name)` to refer to it later. The `fully_connected()` function does not have `name` as an argument.

Is there another way to refer to output_layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the complete "path" of the tensor accessing the `.name` attribute:

```
print(output_layer.name)
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I refer to the output_layer in another function though? When I take the name printed from your code and use get_tensor_by_name it can't find it.

Comment: It should find it if the it has been defined in the current graph

Comment: Got it, i excluded the "/" in the name. Working now. Thank you!!